# How to search for places along a route?

Tags: google-maps

I often try to integrate some errands in trips while I'm underway. For instance, I might look for a specific kind of store that is reasonably close to where I pass by.

I am trying to find out how to drive from A to B *and* where to find such a store using Google Maps.

As far as I have found out, I can find routes from A to B. Google Maps will then suggest several alternative routes and display them in the map.

However, it seems that while these routes are displayed, there is no way to search for the stores I am interested in. For that, I have to click the *X* to close the route search (which makes the routes disappear in the map), only then, the search box for searching for places appears again.

**How can I display both the places and the routes at the same time (without going through workarounds of having to log in to Google and save maps temporarily)?**

There seems to be only one similar question from 2010:

- [*Search restaurants (POIs) along a route with google maps*](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3207/search-restaurants-pois-along-a-route-with-google-maps)

However, it focuses on the mobile version of Google Maps, and about desktop use of Google Maps, the question claims

> Just realized that there's a workaround for a machine with sufficient screen size - just set the route on google maps and enter your favourite restaurants name in the search box.

As far as I can tell, this is simply not true in the current version of Google Maps, as it is impossible to display the search box and display a route at the same time.

Comment: I have this same question too. The Google Maps app on iOS does it pretty well. It's disappointing that the Google Maps website doesn't seem to have this feature. It would be great if the website allowed a real "search along my route" feature and then displayed little info dots/bubbles on the map of each of the search results.

Comment: @Ryan: I am not sure Google Maps can sensibly know what is or is not "along my route" (depending on the location and urgency of the intermediate stop, deviations from the original route may or may not be acceptable).

Comment: It already works well on their Google Maps iOS app. They should just copy the same user interface onto the web.

Comment: @Ryan: I'll check that one out (but I don't currently know anyone in my place who owns any Apple devices, so it might take a while, though).

Answer (score 8):

The earlier answer correctly points out that you can roughly do this in Google maps. However it does not lay out the alternatives very clearly.

[Road.li](http://road.li) lets you put in your start point, end point, and a query, and it will show you places that match the query along your route. It also shows how much time each place adds to your trip.

It is a tool that I created. It should work fine on both desktop and mobile.

Comment: Clever. Bookmarked.

Comment: That's a nice tool!

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does it work? Does it add each point that matches the query to the route and then finds the shortest of these. Or does google have some clever api call?

Comment: Does this site still work?

Comment: @stannius looks like it had bitrotted, but I got it back up and running again! Google had made some breaking changes to the Google Places API. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: You're welcome, but thanks to YOU for creating and supporting the tool! https://imgflip.com/i/7jfy2q

Comment: @doug I'm trying to email you via the email on the site due to a bug I found but the mail server isn't receiving emails.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Google maps]

Example map: The white circle shows you that you can add places, and the grey shows how you can move them. Highlighted is places near the route.

You can search for the specific place that you SEE and add it. 
Or simply just type in the specific store/place and find the closest one.

Is this what you meant?

Comment: What would be better is if Google Maps allowed a real "search along my route" feature and then displayed little dots on the map of each of the search results. The Google Maps app on iOS does it pretty well. It's disappointing that the Google Maps website doesn't seem to have this feature.

Comment: Not quite; the order of intermediate stops depends on their location (which I do not know yet at the time of searching), and I might even drop some of them if none are near my main route. Also, I normally do not look for a specific store name, but for a category such as *grocery store* or *gas station*. Searching for those on Google Maps typically yields quite some false positives, and I may not want the (geographically) nearest one anyway, but the most conveniently reachable one. Hence, I cannot rely on Google Maps just picking "the closest one".